# max data transfer rate on RAID array

Tags: raid, database-performance

1) Let's say I have an array of twelve disc drives in a RAID-1 formation.  That's effectively six drives presented for use.  What's the maximum read rate I should be able to get out of that array?  Let's say each drive maxes out at 40 MB/sec.  Does that mean I should be able to read (up to) 240 MB/sec from that array?  Or will I only ever be able to get a maximum of 40 MB/sec read rate, regardless of how many drives in the array?

2) If the answer to the first question is 240 MB/sec and yet I'm getting only 40 MB/sec out of that array, what could be the problem?  Where do I start diagnosing this?

3) As you've probably guessed by now, this is an actual problem I'm having right now.  Up until recently I was able to read up to 200 MB/sec out of this array, but then, after a simple re-boot of the server, I'm getting just 35 MB/sec.  What could possibly have caused this?  I'm baffled.  There doesn't appear to be anything physically wrong with the hardware.  All appears to be working normally.  What am I missing?  Some "parallelize/striping" parameter that has reset itself?  A dead battery in the RAID controller?  The RAID array in question is directly attached within a PowerEdge server, which in turn is used to host a SQL Server instance.  The RAID array stores the files for just one database.

Any and all help gratefully received!

Comment: Why not use RAID 10?

Answer (score 0):

The *Read performance* of RAID-1 is equal to the sum of all member disk since any read request can be handled by any of the drives. This is however, dependent on I/O Load.

The *Write performance* is only equal to the speed of the a single disk. If your disks have different write speeds, this is based on the lowest speed.

If the issue is slower reads, then it's possible that **(a)** one or more of the disks are degraded. In such case, the RAID would still work but that would impact the performance of the system until the disks are replaced. **(b)** You have other I/O going on in the background that's eating up your disk performance. You can try to check using **top** command in Linux or **task manager** in Windows.